# ASP.NET CORE SignalR runs inside Windows Server and locally, but outside does'nt run

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iis, websocket, signalr

I have a project ASP.NET Core 2.1 + Angular. I also use SignalR for notifications. When I run my project, SignalR works normally. After I published it and deployed to my Windows Server 2016 (IIS 10 version). Then I tried to run it in Windows Server, but it failed. Then in "Server Manager" => "Add roles and features" I installed "Websocket protocol". Then my project started work inside Windows Server. But outside it still doesnt work.

It is when I run my project inside WebServer. There is everything ok.

[image: It is when I run my project inside WebServer]

It is when I tried to access my project from outside. Here I have errors

[image: It is when I tried to access my project from outside]

Here is my Startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){

....
services.AddCors();
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

       
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(c =>
{
     c.RootPath = "wwwroot/dist";
});


    services.AddHangfire(config =>
            config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
                .UseMemoryStorage());

        services.AddHangfireServer();

        services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc(
        config => {
            foreach (var formatter in config.InputFormatters)
            {
                if (formatter.GetType() == typeof(JsonInputFormatter))
                    ((JsonInputFormatter)formatter).SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                        Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
            }
               
            })
        .AddJsonOptions(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();
}

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
         IRecurringJobManager recurringJobManager, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        //env.EnvironmentName = EnvironmentName.Production;
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            //app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();        

        app.UseCulture();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
        //.AllowAnyOrigin()
         .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader()
         .AllowCredentials());

        app.UseSignalR(route =>
        {
            route.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notification");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action=index}/{id}");
           
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
       

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwroot";
        });    

        app.UseHangfireDashboard();

        recurringJobManager.AddOrUpdate(
            "Run every 30 minutes",
            () => serviceProvider.GetService<IDocRepository>().CheckDocTasksAndUpdate(),
            "*/30 * * * *"
            );
    }
```

This is my Program.cs file

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        try
        {
            logger.Debug("init main");
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //NLog: catch setup errors
            logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
        
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
             .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
             {
                 logging.ClearProviders();
                 logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
             })
            .UseNLog();  // NLog: Setup NLog for Dependency injection;           
}
```

This is NotificationHub.cs file

```
 public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendNotificationToUsers(List<string> userNames, NotificationModel notification)               // Two parameters accepted
    {
        await Clients.Users(userNames).SendAsync("SendNotificationToUsers", notification);    // Note this 'SendNotificationToUsers'
    }

    public async Task SendNotificationToUser(string userName, NotificationModel notification)                // Two parameters accepted
    {
        await Clients.User(userName).SendAsync("SendNotificationToUser", notification);    // Note this 'SendNotificationToUser'
    }

    public async Task<string> GetConnectionId() => await Task.FromResult(Context.ConnectionId);

}
```

this is signal-r-servise.ts file

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";
    import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { NotificationModel } from '../Class/NotificationModel';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SignalRService {
      public notification: NotificationModel;
    
      public Notifications: NotificationModel[] = [];
      private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
    
      public hasNewNotification: boolean = false;
    
      hasNotification = new Subject<NotificationModel>();
    
      public startConnection = () => {
        this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
                // .withUrl('http://localhost:5000/notification',{
                //   skipNegotiation: true,
                //   transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
                // })
                .withUrl('/notification',{
                  skipNegotiation: true,
                  transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
                })
                .build();
    
        this.hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 100000;
    
        this.hubConnection
          .start()
          .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))
      }
    
      public addNotificationListener = () => {
        this.hubConnection.on('SendNotificationToUser', (notification) => {
          this.notification = notification;
          this.Notifications.push(notification);
          this.Notifications = Array.from(this.Notifications.reduce((m, t) => m.set(t.date, t), new Map()).values());
          console.log("New notification! => ");
          console.log(notification);
          this.hasNewNotification = true;
        });
      }
    
      public SendNotification = () => {
        this.hubConnection.invoke('SendNotificationToUser', this.notification)
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
      }
    
      public notificationsCount(){
          return this.Notifications.length;
      }
    }
```

How can I fix this problem?

This is error in chrome

[image: This is error in chrome]

Answer (score 0):

Now I checked, and realised that signalR works on Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge browsers, but on Chrome doesnt.